# Android gridview for creating puzzle in multiple screens

Tags: android, gridview, imageview, screen, puzzle

I have a problem with making UI for a puzzle in android that support multiple screens!
Desired puzzle is something like this:

[image: Puzzle]

I used GridView and set image in each cell.(Each cell has a distinct image)
I don't know how set dimensions of Gridview and it's cells (Row Height/Col Width) without using screen resolution! :(
images have 1:1 aspect ratio and must stretch in cells.

What I did:

**row_grid.xml**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:padding="0dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/item_image"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/icon2" >
        </ImageView>
</FrameLayout>
```

**Activity_main.xml**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/katy">

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:horizontalSpacing="0dp"
        android:numColumns="2"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:verticalSpacing="0dp" >

    </GridView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

</FrameLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.test;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.R.dimen;
import android.R.integer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    GridView gridView;
    ArrayList<Item> gridArray = new ArrayList<Item>();
    CustomGridViewAdapter customGridAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //Remove App TitleBar
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        txt.setText(Integer.toString(width)+" x "+Integer.toString(height));


        Bitmap block  = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.icon1);
        Bitmap block2 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.icon2);
        Bitmap block3 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.icon3);
        Bitmap block4 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.icon4);

        gridArray.add(new Item(block));
        gridArray.add(new Item(block2));
        gridArray.add(new Item(block3));
        gridArray.add(new Item(block4));

        gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1);

        ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = gridView.getLayoutParams();
        layoutParams.height = 300; //this is in pixels
        layoutParams.width  = 300; //this is in pixels
        gridView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);


        customGridAdapter = new CustomGridViewAdapter(this, R.layout.row_grid, gridArray);
        gridView.setAdapter(customGridAdapter);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Result:

[image: result]

How can I make it independent of screen size and resolution?! :(

Edit:
I tried to change width of GridView dynamically, but fatal exception occured !

```
package com.example.test;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.R.dimen;
import android.R.integer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    GridView gridView;
    ArrayList<Item> gridArray = new ArrayList<Item>();
    CustomGridViewAdapter customGridAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //Remove App TitleBar
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //Get Screen Dimensions
        Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);
        int width = size.x;
        int height = size.y;

        final TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        txt.setText(Integer.toString(width)+" x "+Integer.toString(height));

        Bitmap block  = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.icon1);
        Bitmap block2 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.icon2);
        Bitmap block3 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.icon3);
        Bitmap block4 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.icon4);

        gridArray.add(new Item(block));
        gridArray.add(new Item(block2));
        gridArray.add(new Item(block3));
        gridArray.add(new Item(block4));

        gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1);

        //###### Change Height of cells #####//
        LinearLayout rg = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.layout.row_grid);
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams rgparam = rg.getLayoutParams();
        rgparam.height = rgparam.width;
        rg.setLayoutParams(rgparam);          

        customGridAdapter = new CustomGridViewAdapter(this, R.layout.row_grid, gridArray);
        gridView.setAdapter(customGridAdapter);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

also I tested this:

```
    customGridAdapter = new CustomGridViewAdapter(this, rg.getId(), gridArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at Relative Layout. I believe it will solve your problem. You specify where the image lies and what it is adjacent to. So in the above image, box 2 would be to the right of box 1 and aligned to the top of the parent view. Box 1 would be aligned to the top and the left of the parent.

Comment: How can I define width and height of cells according to screen resolution? Row count and Col count of grid is fix(9x6)

Comment: I would look at the canvas/screen height and width and divide appropriately. Then I'd use the Path class to create box shapes based on those dimensions. I'd fill those boxes with the same background colour as the image and centre the image inside each box (not sure how to do that but I've seen questions asked about it when searching for other questions). You would be creating your own view doing this which is a different approach from my original answer.

Comment: I tried to resize "row_grid" layout dynamically according to screen size, but a run-time error has occurred and app terminated !!!

Answer (score 1):

```
Try with below code and check if its working or not?  



        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:padding="0dp" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/item_image"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" >
                </ImageView>

            </LinearLayout>

    -------------------------------

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/background" >

        <GridView
            android:id="@+id/gridView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:horizontalSpacing="0dp"
            android:numColumns="3"
            android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
            android:verticalSpacing="0dp" >
        </GridView>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you kindly. I tried this before. everything is good, but row height is not correct! Row height in Gridview must be equal to Cell width, but I think it is equal to original image height(300px) !!! This is result: http://s1.uploads.im/GhseS.png

Comment: @Jessica yup, I have seen it, just check my edited answer and check, if this will work then its grt, if not work then, let me know. I will give you another code.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately it does not work! Look at this: http://i.imgur.com/nQ87UZa.png ; right side of images are cropped!!! In addition I don't want to use absolute width & height(100dp). I tried to set row_grid.height equal to row_grid.width but run-time error occured!

Comment: @jessica I think you have to use dynamic width and height, can you please send me the code of yours, let me do it for you and will send it to you back.

Comment: @Jessica hey, can you send me your cdoe, let me check in my editor.

Comment: Download from here: http://www.megafileupload.com/en/file/544306/Android-zip.html